# How to put a decimal point according to the will of the user in a calculator in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode, xcode4

I have a calculator in which i would like to put the decimal point according to the button press for the decimal point. I get the decimal point but if I enter another digit the decimal pint vanishes and is overwritten .

The code is mentioned below for the decimal press:-

```
-(IBAction)decimalPressed:(id)sender{
  calculatorScreen.text = [calculatorScreen.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}
```

For the digit press it is :-

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender{
  currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + (float)[sender tag];
  calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
}
```

How can i do something like 23 then "." then 45. The result would be 23.45

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've recently done a calculator app and could understand your problem. Another thing you want to take note about the point is that you do not want to have multiple point in your calculation, e.g. 10.345.1123.5. Simply put, you want it to be a legal float number as well.

With that said, you can use a IBAction (remember to link it to your storyboard or xib file)

```
-(IBAction)decimalPressed:(UIButton *)sender
{
 NSRange range = [self.display.text rangeOfString:@"."];
if (range.location ==NSNotFound){
self.display.text = [ self.display.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
}
self.userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber = YES;
}
```

While it might be possible we are doing on the same project, it could also be entirely different (you starting from scratch by yourself) so i will go through some of the codes

you could replace UIButton with the default id, but it is better to static replace it to make clear clarification for yourself, or anyone else who view your code.

NSRange as the name implies, mark the range, and the range will be ur display text of calculation (e.g. 1235.3568), and the range of string it is targeting in this case is "."
therefore, if NSNotfound (rangeOfString "." is not found in the text range) you will append the current display text with "." with the function stringByAppendingString:@".", there is no else, so no function will take place if "." is already found, which solve the problem of multiple point on the display.

userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber is a BOOL to solve the problem of having 0 in ur display (e.g. 06357), if you have a method to change it, then replace my method name with your own.

Comment: display and userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber is not found . Why is this so ?

Comment: display would be your 1st label (if you name your label differently, name it accordingly.)  userIsInTheMiddleOfEnteringANumber is a global BOOL variable which I've use to eradicate the problem of input number starting with 0 e.g. 0615, as the default start out screen for calculator is set to 0

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code:

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
     UIButton *pressedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
     calculatorScreen.text = [calculatorScreen.text stringByAppendingFormat:@"%d",pressedButton.tag];
     currentNumber = [calculatorScreen.text floatValue];
}
```

Comment: Property tag is not found on the object . The error is on the sender tag . Any other solution ?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(IBAction)ButtonDot
{
    decimalChecker = 10;
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %g.", currentSavings];
    decimalChecker=1;

}

-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender
{
if (decimalChecker ==1) 
{        
    currentDecimal = currentDecimal*10 + (float)[sender tag];
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %g.%g",      currentSavings,currentDecimal];       
}
else
{
    currentSavings = currentSavings*10 + (float)[sender tag];
    calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$ %g",currentSavings];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    float result;
    IBOutlet UILabel *TextInput;
    int currentOperation;
    float currentNumber;
    BOOL userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal;
}

- (IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)cancelInput;
- (IBAction)cancelOperation;
- (IBAction)dotPressed;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()


@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}

- (IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender {
    if(!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal)
    {
        currentNumber = currentNumber*10 + (float)[sender tag];
        TextInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",(int)currentNumber];
    }
    else{
        TextInput.text= [TextInput.text stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[sender tag]]];
        currentNumber = [TextInput.text floatValue];
    }
}

- (IBAction)buttonOperationPressed:(id)sender {
    if (currentOperation == 0) result = currentNumber;
    else {
        switch (currentOperation) {
            case 1:
                result = result + currentNumber;
                break;
            case 2:
                result = result - currentNumber;
                break;
            case 3:
                result = result * currentNumber;
                break;
            case 4:
                result = result / currentNumber;
                break;
            case 5:
                currentOperation = 0;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
    currentNumber = 0;
    TextInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",result];
    if ([sender tag] == 0) result = 0;
    currentOperation = [sender  tag];
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;
}

-(IBAction)cancelInput{
    currentNumber = (int)(currentNumber/10);
    TextInput.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f",currentNumber];;
}

-(IBAction)cancelOperation{
    currentNumber = 0;
    TextInput.text = @"0";
    userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = NO;
}
- (IBAction)dotPressed{
    if(!userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal){
        userInTheMiddleOfEnteringDecimal = YES;
        TextInput.text= [TextInput.text stringByAppendingString:@"."];
    }
}

@end
```

Hope this helps.. Another way of solution...

Answer (score -1):

after pressing the "." all values after will be divided as following
the first number ur press after pressing "." will be divided by 10 the second by 100 and so on

so editing ur function it would be like this

```
-(IBAction)buttonDigitPressed:(id)sender{
  currentNumber = currentNumber + (float)[sender tag] / 10.0;
  calculatorScreen.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",currentNumber];
}
```

Comment: and what if you want `32` as a number? After first click you will get `0.3` and after second it will be `0.5`

Comment: You will have to elaborate more on the code, but basically you will have to divide the value after entering the "." by 10 then by 100

Comment: as a pseudo code

if "." is entered
number of digits after the "." = x 
new number = old number + (newnumber)/ (x * 10)

try to implement it

Comment: isn't it a lot more complex than just using `doubleValue` or `floatValue` method? Don forget, that `A good programmer is a lazy programmer`.

Answer (score -1):

i think in that solve your problem

http://www.datasprings.com/resources/articles-information/iphone-sdk-getting-started-example-code

There is sample code of calculator.